# Using hyperref with \addcontentsline

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I have a document with a (logical) section that does not have a standard heading (i.e., no `\section` or whatever), and I would like it to appear in the table of contents and in the PDF bookmarks. I can *almost* do it by using `\addcontentsline`: It is detected by hyperref, but the bookmark that it generates is broken. Clicking on it takes me to the previous bookmark.

I know how to generate a working bookmark with `\pdfbookmark[1]{Section without standard heading}{uniqueID}`, but I also want to see the section in the TOC. (Naturally, using both commands gives me two bookmarks, one of them broken.)

The problem is unchanged when I set `hypertexnames=false` (which is supposed to generate unique identifiers). Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bookmarks,hypertexnames=false,debug]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{First page}

\newpage
\textbf{Text on page 2}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section without standard heading} % broken bookmark
% This will work, but I still need the TOC
%\pdfbookmark[1]{Section without standard heading}{page2}
Second page text

\newpage
\section{Third section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add an target for the link with `\phantomsection`

Comment: That did it, thanks! I'll accept Heiko's answer, unless you want to add your own...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need an anchor for `\addcontentsline`. The anchor is usually set by a section command. This allows the bookmark by `\addcontentsline` to point to the section title and not to the place, where `\addcontentsline` is issued.

An anchor can be set by `\phantomsection`. If the bookmark should point to the bold text on page 2, then put `\phantomsection` right after `\newpage`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bookmarks,hypertexnames=false,debug]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\section{First page}

\newpage
\phantomsection
\textbf{Text on page 2}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section without standard heading}
Second page text

\newpage
\section{Third section}

\end{document}
```

I have added package `bookmark` for faster updated bookmarks.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Would you know why hyperref doesn't do this automatically? I.e. hook into `\addtocontents` (or lower-level equivalent), rather than \section et al. directly. Is it an oversight/design flaw or are there good reasons?

Comment: @alexis It does not hook into `\addtocontents`, but `\addcontentsline`.  This is the markup command for adding entries to the table of contents. Bookmarks of the PDF format are a similar feature semantically.

Comment: Oops, `\addcontentsline` is what I meant (and what I used in my question). Hyperref makes bookmarks from them, but it does not create corresponding destinations as it does with `\section` etc. Is this for a good reason?

Comment: @alexis Often `\addcontentsline` is added *after* the section command. If `\addcontentsline` sets an anchor, then the bookmark would point *after* the section title. Therefore no anchor is set and the latest current anchor is used. If `\addcontentsline` is used before the section title, then it is easy to add `\phantomsection`.

Comment: I would like to add that the command `\phantomsection` can also be used to add Chapters to TOC in the same way. One just does `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{....}`