# Using \ref to refer to a section included in a document using \addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks, ref

*I realize that this question appears to be similar to the following but it is different:*

[Using hyperref with \addcontentsline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247158/using-hyperref-with-addcontentsline)

*I was unable to use the link above to solve my problem.*

I am writing a document using the `book` class.

There is a preamble which has notation and the preamble should not have a chapter number in the table of contents.

Code for notation in preamble:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notation}
\phantomsection
\label{chnotation}

% table of notation goes here
```

In the main body I am using hyper ref to try and get links to pages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[bookmarks,hypertexnames=false,debug,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={blue!90},citecolor={blue!90},urlcolor={blue!80}}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\include*{Preamble/acknowledgements}

\clearpage
\listoftables 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\clearpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\clearpage
\chapter*{Notation}
\include*{Preamble/notation}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents 

\include{"Sections/Chapter 1/chapter1"} 
\include{"Sections/Chapter 2/chapter2"}
\end{document}
```

The result of the table of contents page is given below

[image]

this is **correct** since the sections in the preamble should not have a chapter number associated with them.

I would like to use use `\ref` to refer to the notation section, however using `\ref{chnotation}` (where `chnotation` is the label of the notation section) does not work. I get the following error message

```
Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 16.
```

Is there away I can use `\ref` to refer to a section in the preamble that has been set up this way? I can not use `\chapter` because this will cause a chapter number to appear (along with the text "Chapter XX Notation) and this should not happen since this is part of the preamble.

**Desired outcome**

I would like to write a something like the following in the body:

```
The reader may wish to refer to the \ref{chnotation} in the preamble.
```

and after compiling, the `\ref{chnotation}` will be replaced by the name of the section in the preamble and the sentence will appear as

The reader may wish to refer to the Notation in the preamble.

where clicking on the word "Notation" will take the reader to the page where the `\label{chnotation}` was placed.

I tried looking at

[Using hyperref with \addcontentsline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247158/using-hyperref-with-addcontentsline)

for help however I couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: As it says in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247158/using-hyperref-with-addcontentsline, just add a `\phantomsection` before `\label{chnotation}`.

Comment: @Andrew I tried that but unfortunately it does not work. I have edited my posting to reflect this. I still get the same warning message.

Comment: @Andrew Unfortunately https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247158/using-hyperref-with-addcontentsline does not work. I have even mentioned that in my posting that I referred to it but couldn't use it to solve my problem.

Comment: What text are you expecting to get from your `\ref` to an unnumbered chapter? Normally `\ref` is going to give you the value of the last counter incremented with `\refstepcounter`

Comment: @DonaldHosek I have edited the post and added information on the desired outcome at near the bottom

Comment: @NM_ You said only that you "tried looking at" the other post without saying what you actually did. Before posting my comments I checked and using `\phantomsection` and `\autoref` does solve your problem.

Comment: `\ref` won't work since there is no number.  But with `\phantomsection` you should be able to use `\nameref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\ref` ususally just returns the number fo a chapter. Since you seem to want `\ref` to return the title of an unnumbered chapter, use `\nameref` instead:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,openany,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[bookmarks,hypertexnames=false,debug,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={blue!90},citecolor={blue!90},urlcolor={blue!80}}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{Notation}  \label{ch:notation}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notation} 

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents 

\chapter{chapter heading}
text \nameref{ch:notation}
\end{document}
```